# Unhandled Control Character, chr(32) is not readable by my vb app

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ascii

I am reading a Microsoft Office Word text from a vb.net app, and then storing the formatted string in another ans file. Somewhere in this file I am finding 4 unreadable characters. I went in debug mode and I found out that the Asc code of each of these characters is 32 !!
Normally this is the space code, although I used:

rettext = Replace(rettext, " ", "" )

and

rettext = Replace(rettext, Asc(32), "" )

and

rettext = Trim(rettext)

but still the rettext variable is not changed and have the same length!!

Anyone have an idea what to do ??
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ASCW() instead of ASC()? [Asc, AscW Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**Asc** returns the code point, or character code, for the input character. This can be 0 through 255 for single-byte character set (SBCS) values and -32768 through 32767 for double-byte character set (DBCS) values.

**AscW** returns the Unicode code point for the input character. This can be 0 through 65535. The returned value is independent of the culture and code page settings for the current thread.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I got to this old question of mine and noticed that you added your comment as an answer and didn't check it back then, so I did now! thanks again.

Comment: This resolved the same question for me.  ASCW returned 12288 while ASC said it was just 32 (although mychar = chr(32) returned false).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ASCW works for this case :)

Answer (score 0):

The replace and trim return a string that is changed, it does not change the original string. You should try these instead:

```
rettext = Replace(rettext, " ", "" )
```

and

```
rettext = Replace(rettext, Asc(32), "" )
```

and

```
rettext = Trim(rettext)
```

Comment: Oh I did that, sorry I must have written the code line properly:
rettext=Replace(rettext, " ", "" )

and

rettext=Replace(rettext, Asc(32), "" )

and

rettext=Trim(rettext)

Comment: BTW, in vb.net, you should use stuff like `rettext = rettext.Replace(" ","")` or `rettext = rettext.Trim` instead. Those functions are carry-overs from VB6 (and before). With your above comment, I am confused, you changed it to be this and now it works or you already had it like this but just posted the wrong code?

Comment: no I already had it like this. Btw even if I print this weird character in the immediate window and I copy and paste it in a string var, it does not recognize it as a space but still gives the ascii code 32 :S

And thx for your comment, I will stick to the new concept of using those functions.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. 32 is 32. I would assume you know it is 32 by doing something like this: `For i as integer = 0 to rettext.Length -1`   `debug.writeline(chr(rettext.substring(i,1))`

Comment: Yes Steve I did something like that and it gives me 32. I think maybe it is because I am reading the text from a word file, maybe it is a character not recognized as ascii code ?!

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong thing above, I should have said ASC(), not CHR(). Wrong direction.

Comment: Have you tried ASCW() instead of ASC()?  [Asc, AscW Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I will put as an answer for future searchers then.